# Tensorflow on windows in a vmware virtual machine

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, virtual-machine

I'm getting the following error when trying to use tensorflow within my Python/Jupyter environment:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Problem: I'm running it in a windows virtual machine environment and realized that tensorflow (which is GPU centric) may not like that, or it may be having problems because it's expecting a physical machine instead of a virtual one.

Comment: Don't have much experience with tf on Windows. Install it via anaconda. `conda install tensorflow` will try to bring everything needed with it. Also, tensorflow has two packages: `tensorflow` and `tensorflow-gpu`. GPU is used by the second one. As you correctly suggested, passing physical gpu to virtual machine is another challenge.

Comment: Thank you for this.  Your comment helped!  I had to completely uninstall anaconda, then reinstall it.  I then manually installed tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu using conda as per your suggestion.  It seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

I had to completely uninstall anaconda, then reinstall it. I then installed tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu using the "conda" command as per Slowpoke's suggestion. It seems to be working now.